# How to find path of my folder

Tags: java

We are working on project.
Every colleague have different folder for the install
In my case the folder of my files is in

`C:\\p4_3202\\CAR\\car.rt.appl\\dev\\car.components\\cars\\res\\car.rt.components.cars\\resources\\js;`

for other colleague it could be in

`C:\\my_3202\\CAR2\\car.rt.appl\\dev\\car.components\\cars\\res\\car.rt.components.cars\\resources\\js;`

it is depends how you config your perforce.

I need to read files from my folder but i don't know the name of the folder ( as i explained it could be different )

```
 File folderFile = new File(folder);
```

How i can find the location of my folder ? ( c:\p4\......test.js )
I tried with

```
 System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
 System.getProperty("user.home")
```

but it didn't give me the path of my folder

Comment: What do you mean by *"my folder"*?

Comment: the folder that the files of the java are located in the eclipse

Comment: in my case C:\p4_3202\CARS\cars.rt.appl\dev\new_car\

Comment: Either refer to it as a full path, or by a relative path.

Comment: I don't have the name of the folder I want to find it

Comment: @user1365697 : Can you explain your question with example? Then will be more clearer for what you are looking. Also update this info by editing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a system property for each user. So all users tell where perforce is installed (might already exist a property for this, look at the docs).
This could then be read by your code like:

```
 System.getenv().get("PROP");
```

On a unix/Linux system you can set the property in a shell/environment variable using:

```
 export PROP=thepath
```

Windows was a long time ago for me but if I remember correctly its somewhere under System on control panel :)

Update: 
     http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

Comment: When i did it String str = System.getProperty("PROP"); I got null as result

Comment: Did you export (or set) the property before? Otherwise null is to be expected ;)

Comment: I didn't set before when I need to set the Property

Comment: Did you read my answer? You need to set the property as a system property before accessing it. How to do this is os dependent, looking at your examples I'd guess your on windows. Updated answer with a link.

Comment: I did it but I still don't get any value.

Comment: Still no luck getting the property ?

Comment: I'd say this is the only valid solution. Since the location can be different for all users they need to let you know where the files are located by exporting a variable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`file.getAbsolutePath()` or `file.getAbsoluteFile()`

Comment: so I need to create empty File object ?

Comment: I don't want to inserted the path of the file as default

Comment: I believe he is looking for a way to find a file and read it. Using your solution, he will have access to the file he is currently reading.

Comment: The issue that the folder could be different folder in different people depends how they install the project

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it are files for reading only, being stored  inside the final produced jar, then use `URL url = getClass().getResource("/.../...")` or `InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/.../...")`.

That uses a path inside the jar/class path. Using only the jar would never do with File.

Comment: what I will do with the result It is not possible to create File with URL